# Import Python package from new environment: module not found error

Tags: python, module, path, anaconda, environment-variables

I installed [Cartopy](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/) in a new conda environment `new_env` because I was unable to install it in my base environment.

I'm now trying to `import cartopy` in Jupyter Lab and am seeing `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cartopy'`.

What could be preventing me from importing this package?

I've confirmed `cartopy` shows up when I `conda activate new_env` and type `conda list`, so it's there.

I've also added the corresponding path `export PATH="$/opt/anaconda3/envs/new_env/bin:$PATH"`, so Python should know where to pull packages from.

Any idea how to resolve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Jupyter notebook, python venv is not activated by `conda activate` command.
This link https://janakiev.com/blog/jupyter-virtual-envs/ will help you.

Comment: That did it, thank you! It was just 3 steps, as outlined in the link you provided.

In terminal: 
`pip install --user ipykernel`, then 
`python -m ipykernel install --user --name=new_env`, then

in Jupyter Lab:
`Kernel` -> `Change Kernel...`